# How Try block knows at what line of statement in a code it has to throw an Exception

Tags: java, exception

For example in number divide by zero how try block identify that at what statement it has to throw the exception. does it check the denominator value implicitly and it does than how it knows

Comment: Are you asking about classic java `try{} catch{}` block ??

Answer (score 1):

Exceptions don't work that way.

The `try{} catch {}` blocks doesn't know anything, as it is not the one throwing an exception, it is just there on how to handle an exception thrown by code inside the `try` block.

In your case, ArithmeticException is thrown at *runtime* by the VM when the denominator is 0, after that the stacktrace is populated as in case of any exception.

> ArithmeticException is thrown when an exceptional arithmetic condition
>   has occurred. For example, an integer "divide by zero" throws an
>   instance of this class. ArithmeticException objects may be constructed
>   by the virtual machine as if suppression were disabled and/or the
>   stack trace was not writable.